# How to add a custom action in Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Markup with SharePoint Designer or PowerShell?

Tags: custom-actions

I'm trying to add a custom action in the `Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Markup` group. My goal is to add a button that fires a custom javascript that inject som html content in the rich editor control of a wiki site (related to my previous question).

When I try with SPD, even if I can write `Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Markup`, the custom action is not displayed.

How can I add such custom action using either SPD or Powershell ?

I've also tried with a Powershell script like this :

```
$site = Get-SpSite "http://server/sites/coll"
$ca = $site.UserCustomActions.Add()
$ca.Name = "test"
$ca.Title = "Test"
$ca.Location = "Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Markup"
$ca.Url = "javascript:alert('Working')"
$ca.Update();
```

Please note this is a custom action used for only one site. I'd like to avoid to create a feature for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if building plain SPD solution could be possible or at least easy. There are ways to extend ribbon actions using javascript, by somehow injecting into the process, but i'm not sure if it can be done truly without server side code.

For example, you could follow this [link](http://sharepointtaproom.com/2011/09/09/manipulating-the-ribbon-in-sharepoint-2010-with-javascript-part-1/) how to manipulate ribbon from javascript, create javascript file using SPD and modify Master Page to include this file.

But i would suggest creating sharepoint solution (even sandbox might be enough).

As for powershell script, you have to include [CommandUIExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.usercustomaction.commanduiextension.aspx) property with valid xml, where you can describe your controls (i.e. buttons) and commands (i.e. javascript:alert('test')

Answer (score 0):

This should help you http://msmvps.com/blogs/cobrien/archive/2010/01/25/adding-ribbon-items-into-existing-tabs-groups-ribbon-customization-part-2.aspx

To only activate for a single sub-site, make sure your Feature is targeted to a WEB, which should then be activated for your web only.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: I've read this article. My question was targeting SPD or maybe PS. Here I'll have to buidl a feature, package, etc. which I wanted to avoid.